# Why is the printing messed up when running multiple threads in python?

Tags: python, multithreading

I decided to run ten threads. They ran correctly, with no errors, but when each one was printed, the result had several lines on the same line.

```
import threading
import time

def do_something():
    print("Sleeping...")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("Done sleeping.")

threads = []

for _ in range(10):
    t = threading.Thread(target=do_something)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

I get the strange output of:

```
Sleeping...
Sleeping...
Sleeping...
Sleeping...
Sleeping...
Sleeping...
Sleeping...
Sleeping...
Sleeping...
Sleeping...
Done sleeping.Done sleeping.

Done sleeping.
Done sleeping.Done sleeping.

Done sleeping.Done sleeping.

Done sleeping.Done sleeping.
Done sleeping.
```

Does anybody know why this happens, and how I could fix it?

Comment: You're using threading, so thread output is handled as it arrives. You might want to re-evaluate this and consider if this is _really_ a problem.

Comment: Yes, but how would they print on the same line?

Comment: I wouldn't rely on stdout in threads too much.  But adding, `print("Done sleeping.", flush=True)` may resolve it.

Comment: That didn't work, I am not sure as to why they're printing on the same line.

Comment: I suspect that the thread writes to stdout at nearly the same time, so the linefeed is interleaved. I wouldn't waste time on it.  Maybe use a threadpool and write to stdout when the thread/worker finishes if you want clean output.

Comment: Ok, thank you for your time, I will look into that.

Comment: @TopOfTech I came across the same result when running multiple threads. Do you know the root cause? It looks like the value and the newline in the value didn't print at the same time.

Comment: I don't even remember what this was for, when I asked this I had little experience and I understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot synchronize thread printing, unless you are using lock.

```
import threading
import time

def do_something():
    lock.acquire()
    thread_name = threading.current_thread().name
    print(str(thread_name)+" Sleeping...")
    time.sleep(1)
    print(str(thread_name)+" Done sleeping.")
    lock.release()

threads = []
lock = threading.Lock()
for _ in range(10):
    t = threading.Thread(target=do_something)
    t.start()
    threads.append(t)

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a good idea to rely on writing to stdout in a thread.
If you want clean output you're probably better off handling the stdout in the main thread/process.

Here's an example of a threadpool.  This is one way you could clean up your output:

```py
import time
from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool

def do_something(n):
    time.sleep(1)
    return n

pool = ThreadPool()

jobs = [1,2,3]
print(f"starting jobs: {jobs}")
for result in pool.imap_unordered(do_something, jobs):
    print(f"Job Completed: {result}")
```