# Threading, creation of multiple threads

Tags: python, multithreading

Ive got an issue: I have a class launching a side exe file (CFD calculation), and manages its progress. I have a batch of directories, each of them contains files required for my CFD package to launch a single task. When I launch my code (and give it a single directory name as an attribute) my class parses files in tis directory to conduct initial check of these files, then creates a .bat with a link to my CFD .exe file, with a number of processes I want to assign for this particular task, launches the task (subprocess.Popen() and manages the solution while the task is being calculated. The class has a number of methods, some are doing initial checks, another one launches the task, some methods are managing the solution process and so on... and the last method called "main_loop" is sequencing all the methods together, it represents a loop, calling initial check methods, calling the method launching the task, waiting for the solution to converge and killing the process once convergency reached.

Since I have a bunch of tasks I am using Threading to multithread them. I create a number of named copies of the class giving different directory names to each, then I create a threads for these copies, target of each thread is "main_loop" method of each class copy and start this threads without joining them. So I want to distribute all the cores my PC has between these tasks. The problem I receive is that almost all of the methods of the class print something. For example initial check method prints some like f"The task in the directory {} has successfully passed initial check!". While multithreading works such messages belonging to different threads can appear together in the screen in one line, it is logical issue of this implementation. but how to separate them? at least I want them to appear on different lines. Probably I can apply threading.Lock at each print function to lock another threads while printing executed. I don't have an idea the way it works.

If the Lock is the solution, are there any other ways to solve the problem? probably it is possible to pipe the printing functions to sequence them, make a queue of them according to which the messages will appear on the screen?

Comment: Use logging instead of printing. [https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html)

Comment: Or - [Why is the printing messed up when running multiple threads in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63460614/why-is-the-printing-messed-up-when-running-multiple-threads-in-python). Quite a few Q&A's suggesting to use a Lock when printing.

Comment: [https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-from-multiple-threads](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#logging-from-multiple-threads)

Comment: To avoid multiple print statements printing on the same line, try adding *flush=True*. For example, `print('This is a message.", flush=True)`

Comment: If using *flush=True* does not resolve your problem, then pass a `threading.Lock` instance to your threads and then: `with lock: print('a message', flush=True)`